# How to convert an int to a hex string?

Tags: python, string, hex, int

I want to take an integer (that will be <= 255), to a hex string representation

e.g.: I want to pass in `65` and get out `'\x41'`, or `255` and get `'\xff'`.

I've tried doing this with the `struct.pack('c',`65`)`, but that chokes on anything above `9` since it wants to take in a single character string.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You are looking for the `chr` function.

You seem to be mixing decimal representations of integers and hex representations of integers, so it's not entirely clear what you need. Based on the description you gave, I think one of these snippets shows what you want.

```
>>> chr(0x65) == '\x65'
True


>>> hex(65)
'0x41'
>>> chr(65) == '\x41'
True
```

Note that this is quite different from *a string containing an integer as hex*. If that is what you want, use the `hex` builtin.

Comment: I thought chr converted integers to ascii. In which case chr(65) = 'A'. Is this a new addition?

Comment: @diedthreetimes, `chr` does not involve ASCII at all--it simply takes a number and makes a one-byte bytestring where the ordinal value of the byte is the number. ASCII and ASCII-compatible encodings come into play when you write and display bytestrings.

Comment: @diedthreetimes, For example, they come in by making `'A'` another way to write and display `'\x41'`. All `str` really cares about is the fact this is sixty-five. To make things understandable and usable by humans, it often becomes an A.

Answer (score 157):

This will convert an integer to a 2 digit hex string with the 0x prefix:

```
strHex = "0x%0.2X" % integerVariable
```

Comment: I suggest to edit the code here and change it to this: strHex = "0x%0.2X" % integerVariable. (I wasn't able to edit myself.)

Answer (score 93):

What about [`hex()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html)?

```
hex(255)  # 0xff
```

If you really want to have `\` in front you can do:

```
print '\\' + hex(255)[1:]
```

Comment: `repr(chr(255)) # '\xff'` also achieves this

Answer (score 84):

Let me add this one, because sometimes you just want the single digit representation

*( `x` can be lower, 'x', or uppercase, 'X', the choice determines if the output letters are upper or lower.)*:

```
'{:x}'.format(15)
> f
```

And now with the new `f''` format strings you can do:

```
f'{15:x}'
> f
```

To add *0* padding you can use `0>n`:

```
f'{2034:0>4X}'
> 07F2
```

> NOTE: the initial 'f' in `f'{15:x}'` is to signify a format string

Comment: For reference on this neat feature, PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation

Comment: IMHO, a bit more "readable" option can be '0x{:X}'.format(15) (notice X is in uppercase). For 2034 it will print 0x7F2 instead of 7f2

Answer (score 51):

Try:

```
"0x%x" % 255 # => 0xff
```

or

```
"0x%X" % 255 # => 0xFF
```

Python Documentation says: "keep this under Your pillow: http://docs.python.org/library/index.html"

Comment: `"%#x" % 255` :)

Answer (score 34):

For Python >= 3.6, use f-string formatting:

```
>>> x = 114514
>>> f'{x:0x}'
'1bf52'
>>> f'{x:#x}'
'0x1bf52'
```

Comment: This should be more upvoted. f-strings for the win :-)

Answer (score 13):

If you want to pack a struct with a value <255 (one byte unsigned, uint8_t) and end up with a string of one character, you're probably looking for the [format B instead of c](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters). C converts a character to a string (not too useful by itself) while B converts an integer.

```
struct.pack('B', 65)
```

(And yes, 65 is \x41, not \x65.)

The struct class will also conveniently handle endianness for communication or other uses.

Comment: The amount of time it has taken me to find struct.pack('B', <integer>) is staggering. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

With `format()`, as per [format-examples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples), we can do:

```
>>> # format also supports binary numbers
>>> "int: {0:d};  hex: {0:x};  oct: {0:o};  bin: {0:b}".format(42)
'int: 42;  hex: 2a;  oct: 52;  bin: 101010'
>>> # with 0x, 0o, or 0b as prefix:
>>> "int: {0:d};  hex: {0:#x};  oct: {0:#o};  bin: {0:#b}".format(42)
'int: 42;  hex: 0x2a;  oct: 0o52;  bin: 0b101010'
```

Answer (score 12):

Note that for large values, `hex()` still works (some other answers don't):

```
x = hex(349593196107334030177678842158399357)
print(x)
```

Python 2: `0x4354467b746f6f5f736d616c6c3f7dL`
Python 3: `0x4354467b746f6f5f736d616c6c3f7d`

For a decrypted RSA message, one could do the following:

```
import binascii

hexadecimals = hex(349593196107334030177678842158399357)

print(binascii.unhexlify(hexadecimals[2:-1])) # python 2
print(binascii.unhexlify(hexadecimals[2:])) # python 3
```

Comment: Well... no. I tried `hex(hash(text))` and it produced a negative integer which resulted in a hex string with minus sign. Who did implement this?

Comment: @JPT I don't understand your question. If the value is negative, then obviously the hex value will have a minus sign. Why would that be different when writing in hexadecimal, binary, decimal, or any other number system? Or are you looking for the in-memory representation, where there is a bit that determines the sign by being set or unset?

Comment: Well, the computer scientist is expecting negative hex to be something starting with a sign flag, so for example FFFx xxxx or 8000 xxxx, not an actual sign. I've never ever seen a hex with a minus sign before. But if you put it like that... ;)

Comment: @JPT the hext values you usually see are just a hex representation of a binary value. It is a matter of coding (Two's complement) that it is used in computer science. In the past different way of representing negative binary numbers were also used but Two's complement has biggest advantages.

Comment: @Filip exactly, that's why a HEX with minus sign is not an exact representation. It's an interpretation.

Answer (score 11):

```
(int_variable).to_bytes(bytes_length, byteorder='big'|'little').hex()
```

For example:

```
>>> (434).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big').hex()
'000001b2'
>>> (434).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little').hex()
'b2010000'
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked best for me

```
"0x%02X" % 5  # => 0x05
"0x%02X" % 17 # => 0x11
```

Change the (2) if you want a number with a bigger width (2 is for 2 hex printned chars) so 3 will give you the following

```
"0x%03X" % 5  # => 0x005
"0x%03X" % 17 # => 0x011
```

Answer (score 7):

Also you can convert any number in any base to hex. Use this one line code here it's easy and simple to use:

`hex(int(n,x)).replace("0x","")`

You have a string `n` that is your number and `x`  the base of that number. First, change it to integer and then to hex but hex has `0x` at the first of it so with `replace` we remove it.

Comment: `hex(int(n,x))[2:]` - not sure which is faster :)

Answer (score 4):

I wanted a random integer converted into a six-digit hex string with a # at the beginning.  To get this I used

```
"#%6x" % random.randint(0xFFFFFF)
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `"#%6x" % random.randint(0x0, 0xFFFFFF)`. (There is a missing `%` before `6` and `randint` takes 2 parameters -lower and upper bounds-)

Comment: should be %06x if you don't want spaces

Answer (score 1):

Use f-strings, it's easy to parse and quite flexible:

```
print(f'{255:x}')         # => 'ff'   
print(f'{15:2x}')         # => ' f'    
print(f'{15:02x}')        # => '0f'    
print(f'\\x{15:02x}')     # => '\x0f'
```

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative representation you could use

```
[in] '%s' % hex(15)
[out]'0xf'
```