# Convert int to hex and make terminal read it as hex

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am trying to convert an integer to hex. I have found answers that address this problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269827/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-hex-string), though they do not work for me. What i mean:

if i take this:

```
buf =  ""
buf += "\xda\xc7\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\xbe\x9d\xca\x88\xfb\x5a\x29"
print buf
```

and i run it from console with python myfile.py then the output is something like this: ���t$���ʈ�Z), which is what i want (the output has been read as hex). If though i try this:

```
var1 = 230
var2 = ""
var2 = "\\" + "x" + "%0.2X" % var1 
print var2
```

the output is **\xE6**, not read as hex by the console. What am i missing here??

Comment: @JaredFields. Look at his code. What is tripping you up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example what you're doing is creating a sequence of escape characters. So when the code has

```
buf = "\xc9"
```

The interpreter is actually converting that to a character encoded by 0xc9 in ascii.

The problem you're having is that your code doesn't allow for these conversions. Your code ask for a string that is just the character \ then x followed by the hex value of some variable.

What you are probably looking for is something like this:

```
var = 230
buf = ""
buf += chr (var1)
```

NOTE: if you need to encode UTF-8 values (basically anything greater than 255 you may want to use unichr() rather than chr().

Comment: Great answer. Wasn't aware of chr().

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks! Otherwise you just do some extra conversions to and from a string in between.

Answer (score 3):

`\xda` is an escape sequence that is interpreted by the Python interpreter. `\` has no meaning by itself, and `\\` is an escape sequence meaning "backslash".

To convert custom hex numbers to text, see this question: [Convert from ASCII string encoded in Hex to plain ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641440/convert-from-ascii-string-encoded-in-hex-to-plain-ascii). Here is a summary of the simplest answer: `("%0.2X" % var1).decode("hex")`.