# python integer format conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, udp

I need an application that will do the following:

1. read UDP message, get data from it - the data is textual, comma separated.
2. build a new message based on this values
3. send a new UDP message to other destination.

For the first and the last I'm fine. for the second I have a challenge:
Lets say that the data I've received is `Year = 2020`. The message on the Wireshark (step 3), I shall see it as 2 bytes valued `07 e4`

How can I do it? I've tried couple of ways, none of them provided me with the desired format.

Sample of the code:

```
data1 = '\xab\xcd\xef\xgh'
...
data, addr = sock.recvfrom (200)
elements = data.decode().split(",")
Date=elements[15].split("/")
Year = int(Date(2))
year = <do something with Year to convert to right format>
newMsg = data1 + year
...
newSock.sendto(newMsg.encode('charmap'), (IP, int(port)))
```

Python version 3.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269827/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-hex-string

Comment: have a look at [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/struct.html), it offers useful functionality for these kinds of message composing, e.g. `struct.pack('!h', 2020)`

Comment: @go2nirvana - no. the assumption there is that the integer is less than 255. I need values greater than that

Comment: @MrFuppes, as mentioned, the original value is textual, comma separated, which includes day and time (aa:bb:cc.dd, XX/YY/ZZ) - I need to extract each of those values and rebuild a new packet, which contains additional data. this data is stored as string

Comment: @user1977050 there is no such assumption. You can use `hex` to convert any integer to hexadecimal.

Comment: I've updated the post with some sample of the code so that it will be more clear what I'm doing.

Comment: if you encode `newMsg` to charmap in the end, I think you should be working with strings beforehand, not bytes. But that would make `'2020'` 4 bytes, not two.

Comment: @MrFuppes therefore I'm looking for a solution to my issue. Maybe I shall do something else at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there seem to be a couple of issues here.  first, if your `data1` is really supposed to be raw bytes then you're better off declaring it as such by prefixing it with a `b`, something like:

```
data1 = b'\xab\xcd\xef\xff'
```

if it comes from somewhere else, then encode it to `bytes` appropriately.

for answering your main question, the `struct` module has useful tools for encoding numbers as bytes in the way you want.  `ctypes` can also be useful, but `struct` tends to be easier to use for these sorts of things:

```
data, addr = sock.recvfrom (200)
elements = data.decode().split(",")
date = elements[15].split("/")
year = int(date(2))
newMsg = data1 + struct.pack('!h', year)
```

and then you can send it with:

```
newSock.sendto(newMsg, (IP, int(port)))
```

Comment: 2 questions: A. I have additional variable called `Month`. when I try to perform a pack, it appends 2 bytes instead of single. How do solve it?
B. I need to calculate checksum on the message. I've tried `sum (newMsg)` but it expects int type

Comment: a. read the docs of [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to see how to pack a byte.  b. checksums are a large subject of their own, mostly unrelated to numerical summation.  I'd suggest searching for existing code that does something similar

Comment: a. just solved it.
b. - previously I had `s=0`  `for k in newMsg:` `sum+=ord(k)` to what shall I change it now?

Comment: `list(b'abc')` evaluates to the same as `[ord(k) for k in 'abc']`